# Mixin won't accept @content block with libsass

Tags: node.js, sass, libsass

The error I get:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing white, a non-string value, to unquote()
will be an error in future versions of Sass.
    on line 56 of src/scss/_library.scss

events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: src\scss\_library.scss
Error: Mixin "media" does not accept a content block.

   Backtrace:
    src/scss/_library.scss:27, in mixin `media-above`
    src/scss/_layout.scss:16
    on line 27 of src/scss/_library.scss
>> @include media($min-query, null) { @content;
   -----------^
```

This is on windows 10 with all other gulpfile configs/tools working fine. I've tried npm update, npm rebuild node-sass, npm reinstall to cheack this. The mixin is loaded before the component styles.

It works fine with ruby-sass, this error appears when I'm using the libsass complier. Any ideas on why the content block cant be accpeted in the mixin?

Comment: Since you've already established that this is an error in LibSass, the appropriate thing to do here is file a bug report with the maintainers.  They're the only ones who can resolve this.

Comment: Already on it, cheers.